# How the total pseudo R2 is calculated with the "dissmfac" function in TraMineR?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, manova, sequence-analysis, traminer

I am using the discrepancy analysis in TraMineR. I performed univariate analysis with "dissassoc" to measure the effect of each variable. Then, I did a multi-factors analysis using "dissmfac" to assess the effect of all the variables. I didn't understand how the total Pseudo R2 is calculated in the multi-factor analysis?

Answer (score 2):

These methods are fully described in the following article:

Matthias Studer, Gilbert Ritschard, Alexis Gabadinho, and Nicolas S. Müller (2011), Discrepancy Analysis of State Sequences, *Sociological Methods & Research* 40: 471-510, doi:http://doi.org/10.1177/0049124111415372

The behavior of these functions may depend on whether the distance matrix is squared or not. In the above reference you can find an in-depth discussion on whether you should square it or not.

By default `dissmfac` square the distance matrix before computing the Pseudo-R2, whereas it is not the case for dissassoc. This is to be consistent with previous literature on the methodology behind `dissmfac`. The `dissmfacw` function does not square the distance matrix by default. In any case, you can change this behavior by using the argument `squared=FALSE` in all the above-mentioned functions.